# JQuery copy/append element, base object removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, clone, jquery-ui-sortable

Trying to clone base element *li.table-field-base* to variable *clonedItem*, change some attributes and data on the new element and then append it to sortable list *ul#tablefield-order-sortable*. The result is that the element is appended, but the base element is removed, though i did copy it first. How could i keep the base element, so i can use it later again?

Following is the piece of relevant code that does the copying/appending part:

```
    var clonedItem = $.extend({}, $('li.table-field-base'));
    $('#tablefield-order-sortable').append(clonedItem);
    $('#tablefield-order-sortable').sortable();
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't really clone the element, you cloned the object containing the element.
To clone DOM nodes in jQuery, you use [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
var clonedItem = $('li.table-field-base').clone();
$('#tablefield-order-sortable').append(clonedItem);
$('#tablefield-order-sortable').sortable();
```