# How to duplicate specific sections of form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code as the following example:

```
<form>
  <label>name</label><input type="text" />
  <label>phone</label><input type="text" />

  <label>color</label><select>
    <option>red</option>
    <option>blue</option>
    <option>green</option>
  </select>

  <label>e-mail</label><input type="text" />
</form>
```

And I want to duplicate only the `select` section if the user needs it via button between the `select` section and the e-mail input field.

I'm not really into JavaScript or jQuery so it would very appreciated if you could also add a clear explanation to your answer.

Comment: Duplicate question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934435/jquery-copy-append-element-base-object-removed

Comment: what do you mean by via button between select section and e-mail input field? You want to add a button between them to duplicate the select element on click?

Comment: follow link given by @Jules and try to implement. If you get any error while doing so, let us know. will help you. `clone()` is the `jQuery` function you should use to do that.

Comment: @BuggyParadox yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JQuery `clone` function to clone your element and then append it where you need it, or if you need to have a different id for each section you need you might want to save an index and set it as an id each time you add a section

```js
var index = 1;
function addColor() {
  var nextSection = '<div id="color-section-' + index++ + '">' +
    '<label>color</label>' +
    '<select>' +
      '<option>red</option>' +
      '<option>blue</option>' +
      '<option>green</option>' +
    '</select><br />' +
  '</div>';
  $(nextSection).appendTo($("#color-section"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my-form">
  <label>name</label><input type="text" /><br />
  <label>phone</label><input type="text" /><br />

  <div id="color-section">
    <label>color</label>
    <select>
      <option>red</option>
      <option>blue</option>
      <option>green</option>
    </select><br />
  </div>

  <label>e-mail</label><input type="text" /><br />
</form>

  <button onClick="addColor()">Add Color</button><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to copy an element. See below example with an explanation.

1. A div element with name "color-selections" contain a initial select tag.

   `<div class="color-selections">
       <select> 
         <option>red</option>
         <option>blue</option>
         <option>green</option>
       </select>
     </div>`
2. There will be unknown number of select tag inside the "color-selections" class. So i use first() method to get first element (Original select tag).

   `$(".color-selections select:first")`
3. Copy the first element using clone().

   `$(".color-selections select:first").clone()`
4. Finally, Append this clone element into "color-selections" class using appendTo() method.

   `$(".color-selections select").first().clone().appendTo(".color-selections");`

```js
function addColor() {
  $(".color-selections select:first").clone().appendTo(".color-selections")
  //OR $(".color-selections select").first().clone().appendTo(".color-selections");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>name</label><input type="text" />
  <label>phone</label><input type="text" />

  <label>color</label>
  <div class="color-selections">
    <select> //$(".color-selections select:first")
      <option>red</option>
      <option>blue</option>
      <option>green</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="+" onclick="addColor();">

  <label>e-mail</label><input type="text" />
</form>
```

I hope design is not an important part of sample code.